# Cannot find Complication icon on Galaxy Watch 4

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-complication, samsung-galaxy-watch-4

I have a watch face for Wear OS that I built several years ago. Recently, users have been complaining of crashes on the Galaxy Watch 4. I picked one up and found that Complication icons aren't properly loading on it. Calling `complicationData.getIcon()` returns an Icon, but calling `loadDrawable()` on that produces a null value. There must be a way to get Complication icons still? Plenty of watch faces have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, the issue at hand is Google's restrictions on package visibility in Android 11+. The fix is to declare `<queries>` in your manifest based on the `ACTION_COMPLICATION_UPDATE_REQUEST` intent filter:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.support.wearable.complications.ACTION_COMPLICATION_UPDATE_REQUEST" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: The [wear watchface library](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:wear/watchface/watchface/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml;l=22) already includes this line for you. Are you not using the latest version of Wear Watchface?

Comment: @ianhanniballake no, I built the watchface five years ago now. Am considering doing a full rewrite one of these days, though.